# Can I use PHP on a client-side mobile application

Tags: php, client-side, html5builder

I installed HTML5 Builder on my PC and I've made my first "hello world" Client Mobile application.
The client page is `uHelloWorld.js`. 
This is Javascript but I was wondering if I can use PHP on a client-side page or is the PHP only for server?

Comment: PHP usually runs on the server, yes.

Comment: PHP is only for the server side .... whenever you use php a call to server is made

Comment: Ok but I'm confuse when I debug the hello world project I see that the cursor goes into uHelloWolrd.php. Is this only when I debug or does it send it the php to the mobile when I deploy to mobile

Comment: The debugger in the IDE of HTML5 Builder

Comment: HTML5 Builder client applications are .php before deployment. After deployment, the PHP bits used for development are striped (the PHP code is executed to generate the client-side code).

No PHP gets to the mobile device. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

Working with a Client mobile application in HTML5 Builder you cannot deploy .php code to the device. In fact you don't deploy .js either. Yes, you write the code in js, but during deployment the code is compiled into .apk (for Android platform) through a build on Android SDK or phonegap service. However you can install KSWEB and try to run your php [KSWEB:server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInJ1LmtzbGFicy5rc3dlYiJd). I have not tried it with HTML5 Builder generated php code but it might work.

What you see in the debugger is true, HTML5 Builder has its root in RadPHP (former Delphi for PHP). These tools were designed to develop php applications using RAD components. So some internal operations may still be referring to the old paradigm. This is by no means a sign of php code to be develope/deployed to mobile using standard HTML5 Builder workflow. Keep in mind again that upon deployment, a conversion takes place.

Answer (score 0):

To run PHP you need to install the PHP interpreter and runtime. Any system where you can install PHP can run PHP scripts.

Now, look for a version of PHP for mobile devices. Basically: there is none.

So: no.